# Rails REST use url to filter an index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

I'm trying to extract JSON records from a Rails app via the REST interface.  I'm using RABL to create the JSON.  I would like records that are greater than a specified created_at.

In the worequests controller, I have this:

```
def index
  if params[:created_at] != nil
    @worequests = Worequest.find(params[:created_at])
  else
    @worequests = Worequest.order(:created_at)
end
```

If I enter this into the browser:

```
http://localhost:5000/worequests?created_at=2012-11-28%2016:37:29.253916
```

I get this:

```
Couldn't find Worequest with id=2012-11-28 16:37:29.253916
```

I copied the datetime from the PG table.

Question1

Why couldn't it find that record?

Question2

To use greater than, should I be able to use something like this in the URL?

```
http://localhost:5000/worequests?created_at>2012-11-28%2016:37:29.253916
```

Question3

If I get that working, how would I then ask for the JSON?

```
http://localhost:5000/worequests?created_at>2012-11-28%2016:37:29.253916.json
```

UPDATE1

Thanks HungryCoder - this now works:

```
http://localhost:5000/worequests?created_at=2013-01-01
```

I get an index list of records greater than that date.

But, How do I get the JSON?

I tried this:

```
http://localhost:5000/worequests?created_at=2013-01-01.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1**

`find` method expects the ID of the record.

If you want to filter using created_at field use where or attribute helper methods

```
@worequests = Worequest.where("created_at = ?", params[:created_at])
```

or,

```
@worequests = Worequest.find_by_created_at(params[:created_at])
```

or,

```
@worequests = Worequest.find_all_by_created_at(params[:created_at])
```

`Worequest.find` is similar to `Worequest.find_by_id` (assuming id is name of primary key)

**Answer 2**
You can't use such format in query string. You can put it in separate variable like

```
http://localhost:5000/worequests?created_at=2012-11-28%2016:37:29.253916&compare=%3E
```

so, comparing greater than may be like:

```
if params[:compare] == '>' 
  @worequests = Worequest.where("created_at > ?", params[:created_at])
end
```

'%3E' is uri encoded version of `>`

**Answer 3**

```
http://localhost:5000/worequests.json?created_at>2012-11-28%2016:37:29.253916
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  How would I make it search for datetimes greater than what's in the param? Just change the = to a >

Comment: yes, just use >. please check updated answer for sample logic

Comment: Thanks - the last one returns the JSON !!

Comment: welcome. but didn't get you what mean by 'the last one returns the JSON !!'

Comment: Answer 3 also showed me where to put the .json - I was trying to put it at the end of the whole url